# Uploading text data to firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a realtime chat app using firebase according to [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0) tutorial. According to the tutorial, this line of code

```
mDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).child(key!!).setValue(message)
```

should write the data present in the message object onto the database.

Everything is working fine except when user presses send button, the text is not getting uploaded to the database (but a key is getting created, and when i manually serach that key in database only null stored there).

Here is the minimal code for **ChatActivity.kt**

```
private const val TAG = "ChatActivity"
const val MESSAGES_CHILD = "messages"

class ChatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mChatAdapter: ChatAdapter
    private lateinit var mLinearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager

    private lateinit var mDatabaseReference: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var mFirebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)
        
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: \n Auth: $mFirebaseAuth")
        mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

        mLinearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        mChatAdapter = ChatAdapter(options)
        //ChatAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

        chat.apply {  //R.id.chat
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = mLinearLayoutManager
            adapter = mChatAdapter
        }

        send_button.setOnClickListener {
            val message = Message(message_entry.text.trim().toString())
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: \n $message")

            val key = mDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).push().key
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: \n Key: $key")
            mDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD). child(key!!).setValue(message)
        }
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        mChatAdapter.stopListening()
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause: ")
        super.onPause()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume: ")
        mChatAdapter.startListening()
    }
}

@IgnoreExtraProperties
data class Message(var text: String?= "", var name: String?= "", var id: String?= "") {

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "Text: $text \n Name: $name \n Id: $id"
    }
}
```

Here is the application **debug details**

```
2020-10-17 11:18:34.294 5168-5168/com.skb.skara D/ChatActivity: onCreate:  
Auth: com.google.firebase.auth.internal.zzn@5a3e651  
2020-10-17 11:18:34.338 5168-5168/com.skb.skara D/ChatActivity: onResume:  
2020-10-17 11:18:34.389 5168-5168/com.skb.skara D/ChatAdapter:     getItemCount: 0  
2020-10-17 11:18:34.389 5168-5168/com.skb.skara D/ChatAdapter: getItemCount: 0  
2020-10-17 11:18:37.435 5168-5168/com.skb.skara D/ChatAdapter: getItemCount: 0  
2020-10-17 11:18:37.435 5168-5168/com.skb.skara D/ChatAdapter: getItemCount: 0  
2020-10-17 11:18:42.033 5168-5168/com.skb.skara D/ChatActivity: onCreate:  
Text: Hi  
Name:  
Id:  
2020-10-17 11:18:42.033 5168-5168/com.skb.skara D/ChatActivity: onCreate:  
Key: -MJp5_ulT4U6cXU9Eu41  
2020-10-17 11:18:42.056 5168-5168/com.skb.skara D/ChatAdapter: getItemCount: 1  
2020-10-17 11:18:42.071 5168-5168/com.skb.skara D/ChatAdapter: getItemCount: 1  
2020-10-17 11:18:42.072 5168-5168/com.skb.skara D/ChatAdapter: getItemCount: 1_
```

Here is my **database rules**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I resolved the issue stated in the question. The actual issue is not in the code, but in the emulator I used to run the app. [This](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#prerequisites) link mentions the prerequisites for adding the firebase to an android studio project. In that I forgot to verify whether my emulator has a google play image on it. Today when I was cross verifying prerequisites once again, I found out the issue and after resolving it, now the data is getting uploaded to the firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String key = mDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).push().getKey();
mDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).child(key).setValue(message);
```

`key` means new id for message.

**Update:**
Convert your message object into map:

```
        String key = mDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).push().getKey();

        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("id", message.id);
        result.put("text", message.text);
        result.put("time", message.time);
        result.put("user_name", message.userName);

        HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("/"+ MESSAGES_CHILD + "/" +key, result);

        mDatabaseReference.updateChildren(data);
```

For more information about [read and write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) into Realtime Database

Comment: Key is created. But there is nothing stored in that location.

Comment: Now I tried this way, but sadly this too didn't work. I visited the link you provided and my message class satisfies the requirements given there to write data onto firebase database.

Comment: use `addOnSuccessListener`, `addOnCompleteListener`, `addOnFailureListener` after update children and log something. Like `mDatabaseReference.updateChildren(data). addOnSuccessListener(). addOnCompleteListener(). addOnFailureListener()`

Comment: I added all 4 available listeners (success, failure, complete, canceled) but none of them appeared in the logcat. When I ask for result of the task through `setValue(message).getResult()`  the program halts due to fatal exception saying  _java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete_